Https request to S3 returns error status ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
I have created S3 bucket named "sub.domain.com" to use as Virtual-hosted–style requests. I have mapped my "sub.domain.com" to "sub.domain.com.s3.region-code.amazonaws.com" in DNS records.
Issue is When I used bucket image object in my web app in html img src tag like "https://sub.domain.com/image.jpg", I got (failed)net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error status.
My SSL certificate is wildcard certificate *.domain.com
Bucket is public, Image is accessed by http, but not https.
